# Flutter: ListView rebuilds when keyboard pops up

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app with a page which has a `ListView.builder()` which builds contents from a firestore stream. I want the user to be able to edit the text content of the widget but the widget rebuilds when the keyboard pops up. It works perfectly fine on the simulator when no virtual keyboard pops up.

The issue looks something like this: https://cln.sh/lLj4kf

Code was too long,  I made a gist: https://gist.github.com/HadyMash/c38018da81e5f7692786768dfff134bd

Comment: Could share the minimum reproduction code for this issue?

Comment: @islamakhrarov I have edited my post to include the widget tree, please let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: I don't see any code, unfortunately. Without a minimum reproduction code, no one can help you.

Comment: @islamakhrarov I have uploaded my code https://gist.github.com/HadyMash/c38018da81e5f7692786768dfff134bd.

Comment: Hello @Hady have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hello @AndreasLymbouras, I didn't find an answer. I don't remember if this was a simulator bug or if it also occurred on real devices but I remember I also ran into other issues (don't remember what they were as this was quite a while ago) so I just used the flutter slidable package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) to make an edit button instead. If this problem is occurring just in the simulator, I'd recommend using a real device to test it before trying other solutions. Let me know if there's anything else you need help with.

Comment: Hello, @hady thanks for your reply. I am using a real device and this is happening as well.

Comment: @AndreasLymbouras In that case I believe it is a bug with flutter itself. I would recommend trying to run it on both the `master` and `stable` channels. The stable channel is meant to have only a few updates a year to ensure stability. The master channel has all the latest fixes which is why I also recommend trying it. You can see more here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#switching-flutter-channels. 1/2

Comment: If the issue still happens in that case you can make an issue on the flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose. Choose the second option (I have a problem with my Flutter application.) and fill out the template. 2/2

Comment: No problem! Any time.